# Mailchimp url using power query

Tags: mailchimp, powerbi, powerquery

I'm not a programer, therefore i'm trying to use Power query to pull the data from Mailchimp, the power query allows me to write the url link and to get the data in tables (XMK/Json). 
This is my URL **http://us5.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/reports?apikey=(secret)
and I get only ten reports instead of 100.
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of building your own have you considered using the canned mail chimp content pack? https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-content-pack-mailchimp/ You can signup for Power BI for free to try it.

Comment: Yes Greg but as far as I know I can't save the data as Excel/CSv file. Actually i figured out what is thhe problem I just need to add a parameter count=(as many as I want)  Thanks any way!

Comment: @DavidLerech Nice find! It's good practice on StackOverflow that even if you figure out the answer to your question, write up and post your answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is nowhere documented in mailchimp docs, but by default you get only first ten records when you query a mailchimp 3.0 API. In order to fetch a larger number of records, you have to make use of the `&offset` and `&count` querystring parameters. In one of my recent python projects, I had implemented it as follows to fetch in blocks/pages of 1000 records per request. Perhaps, you might be able to convert it to power-query:

```
campaigns = []
baseurl = "https://" + dc + ".api.mailchimp.com/3.0/"
psize, i = 1000, 0 #page size
while(True):
    turl = baseurl + "reports"
    turl += "?since_send_time=" + camp_since_send_time
    turl += '&offset=' + str(psize * i) + '&count=' + str(psize)
    request = urllib2.Request(turl)
    base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, key)).replace('\n', '')
    request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
    try:
        output = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
        data =  json.loads(output)
    except:
        print "Error occurred. Make sure you entered the correct api key"
        exit()
    MailChimpExpress.createfile("allcampaigns.json", output)
    cnt = len(data['reports'])
    print str(cnt) + " campaigns retrieved"
    for report in data['reports']:
        lst = [report["id"], report["campaign_title"], report["type"], report["emails_sent"]]
        campaigns.append(lst)
    if cnt<psize: break #cnt could also be zero if no records are returned
    i += 1
```

**EDIT**

According to this [technet link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f9fec02-4469-4c56-92ec-00d46b26b3fc/how-to-automateparameterizeloop-power-query?forum=powerquery), looks like you can indeed call urls in succession using power query. You can use a pattern like this one as mentioned in one of the answers:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromColumns({{"firstURL", "secondURL", "etc."}}, {"URLS"}),
    InsertedCustom = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Web.Page(Web.Contents([URLS])))
in
    InsertedCustom
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot Prahlad,It's working however it have a lot of problems to pull this data. What is the parameter offset?

Comment: @DavidLerech The offset parameter specifies the index of next record to pull. For instance, if you pull 100 records in each trip, the `offset` parameter will be 0 for first trip, 99 for next, 199 for the next and so forth, whereas `count` will be 100 for each trip. Hope that helps. If you found my answer helpful, you can accept it by clicking the tick mark on the left.